# Java Derby insert a Java TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, derby

Hello all i have googled for an hour or so  all my test inserts fail. I tried many and  they are commented out. They  fail on the hour of the time stamp insert.
Out of of lines 49 and 50
Students Table created
2017-08-27 21:44:00.318
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "21" at line 1, column 92.

out put of line 51
Students Table created
2017-08-27 21:44:00.318
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "2017" at line 1, column 86.

Any help?

```
    package timeclock;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;



public  class CreateDB {
    public static final String DRIVER= "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:students;create=true";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        isTableExist("STUDENTS");



    }

    public static boolean isTableExist(String sTablename) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        if(connection!=null)
        {
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, sTablename.toUpperCase(),null);
            if(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Table "+rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")+" already exists !!");
            }
            else
            {
                Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                String timefix = time.toString();
                connection.createStatement().execute("create table Students(id INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), FirstName varchar(20), LastName varchar(20), Class varchar(20), ClassNumber INT, StudentIDNumber INT, ClockInTime timestamp, ClockOutTIme timestamp)");
                System.out.println(" Students Table created");
                System.out.println(time);
                //connection.createStatement().execute("insert into Students values " + "('First Name','Last Name','class','123456','123456', To_TIMESTAMP( "+timefix+")" + "," + " To_TIMESTAMP( "+timefix+")"  );
                connection.createStatement().execute("insert into Students values " + "('First Name','Last Name','class','123456','123456',"+timefix+","+timefix+")"  );
                //connection.createStatement().execute("insert into Students values " + "('First Name','Last Name','class','123456','123456', {ts " +timefix+"}" + "," + "ts { "+timefix+"})"  );
                System.out.println(" Students record sucessfully inserted");
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What RBDMS are you running this against, and what is the *exact* SQL being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime in = ZonedDateTime.of( LocalDate.parse( "2017-08-27" ) , LocalTime.parse( "21:00:00" ) , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime out = ZonedDateTime.of( LocalDate.parse( "2017-08-27" ) , LocalTime.parse( "21:45:00" ) , z ) ;
```

Derby 10.13 and later supports JDBC 4.2, so you should be able to use java.time types directly rather than the legacy java.sql types. You should avoid `java.sql.Timestamp` where java.time types are available. (Caveat: I am not a Derby User so I've not tried this.)

Generally best to make a habit of using only [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid the danger of SQL Injection hacking.

The JDBC 4.2 spec requires support for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) but not the more commonly used `Instant` and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes. Converting is easy.

Best to work and think in UTC. So after converting to `OffsetDateTime`, we adjust to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime inOdt = in.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
OffsetDateTime outOdt = out.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Replace my use of ellipsis with your actual arguments and values.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO student_ ( first_name_ , … , clock_in_ , clock_out_ ) VALUES ( ? , … , ? , ? ) ; " ;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
ps.setString( 1 , 'Ben' ) ;
…
ps.setObject( … , inOdt ) ;
ps.setObject( … , inOdt ) ;
…
```

To fetch such values, use `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
OffsetDateTime inOdt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
OffsetDateTime outOdt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust to a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime in = inOdt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime out = outOdt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

---

Naming tips:

Use singular nouns for table names generally, per relational theory.

Append a trailing underscore on your table and column names to avoid collision with reserved words, per SQL spec.

Use all lowercase ASCII letters in names for maximum portability across databases and for simplicity in your SQL coding.

Comment: So this is actually the issue Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: made the change to LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now(); and imported the correct lib.

Comment: ill try the prepared statement

Comment: Took a lot more  googling but you put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

I was guided well by Basil Boutque. It took some finesse but I finally got it.

```
package timeclock;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;



public  class CreateDB {
    public static final String DRIVER= "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:student_;create=true";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        isTableExist("STUDENT_");



    }

    public static boolean isTableExist(String sTablename) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        if(connection!=null)
        {
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, sTablename.toUpperCase(),null);
            if(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("Table "+rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")+" already exists !!");
            }
            else
            {
                //LocalDateTime timeIn = LocalDateTime.now();
                //LocalDateTime timeOut = LocalDateTime.now();
                Timestamp timeIn = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                Timestamp timeOut = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                connection.createStatement().execute("create table STUDENT_(id_ INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), first_name_ varchar(20), last_name_ varchar(20), class_ varchar(20), class_number_ INT, student_id_number_ varchar(6), clock_in_time_ timestamp, clock_out_time_ timestamp)");
                System.out.println(" Students Table created");
                System.out.println(timeIn);
                //connection.createStatement().execute("insert into Students values " + "('First Name','Last Name','class','123456','123456', To_TIMESTAMP( "+time+")" + "," + " To_TIMESTAMP( "+time+")"  );
                //connection.createStatement().execute("insert into Students values " + "('First Name','Last Name','class','123456','123456',"+time+","+time+")"  );
                //connection.createStatement().execute("insert into Students values " + "('First Name','Last Name','class','123456','123456', {ts " +time+"}" + "," + "ts { "+time+"})"  );
                String sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT_ ( first_name_, last_name_, class_, class_number_, student_id_number_, clock_in_time_, clock_out_time_  ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )  " ;
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( sql );
                ps.setString( 1, "Ben" );
                ps.setString( 2, "Tester");
                ps.setString( 3, "DBA");
                ps.setObject( 4, 123456);
                ps.setObject( 5, "649619");
                ps.setObject( 6 , timeIn ) ;
                ps.setObject( 7 , timeOut ) ;
                ps.executeUpdate();
                connection.commit();

                System.out.println(" Students record sucessfully inserted");
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: As you discovered, the core of the solution is to use PreparedStatement and its setObject method, rather than trying to construct a string version of the time data and insert it as a string literal. Not only does this help you deal with complex datatypes such as timestamps, it also makes your application more secure against SQL Injection, etc.